# Export VS Code Java Project for use outside VS Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I have created a Java project in VS Code running the Redhat Java Language Extension for Java. It is not a maven project nor do I know much about what maven actually is.

My project consists of five classes in a single package and uses a handful of imported libraries.

The program is now finished and I would like to be able to run/install it on any machine outside without the use of VS Code (run it like an application). My reading tells me I want to produce a Runnable Jar, but most info I have found is on Eclipse. I don't even know if exporting as a jar is the right choice.

Some posts are pointing me towards maven, but all of my attempts to get it running result in an SSL handshake error due to the firewall, which cannot be changed.

I don't care how it is done, I just want to be able to run my program outside of VS code. How can I do this?

Thank you.

==EDIT==

All classes including the main are in src/app. Project also has the .settings, .vscode, and bin folders generated. Other contents in root are .classpath and .project.

Comment: you need to provide some more details. Pretty sure the extension generated some sort of build instruction. Do you have a pom.xml or graddle file in your root folder?

Comment: Sorry, I'm learning as I go here. I do not have a pom.xml file or gradle file in the root folder. Just .classpath and .project along with the .settings, .vscode, bin, and src folders.

Comment: The .project file could be compatible with eclipse. Anyways it is always a good idea to also have a platform independent build option like maven or graddle. You should probably enhance your question with more details, like your project tree structure.

Comment: Do you mean you want to export your project as a `.jar` file ?